# Windows 10 App - File downloading

Tags: winjs, windows-10

I am working with Windows 10 universal app and i want to download a file in that. The file link to Sharepoint server. I have passed token in headr to a web service and then service returned byte array to my WinJS.

Now i want to save the file, how can i do this? I tried several code samples but not working.

```
var folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder;
folder.createFileAsync("document.docx", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting).then(function (file) {
    return Windows.Storage.FileIO.writeTextAsync(file, result.response);
}).then(function () {
    //saved
});
```

I am using above code and it is creating new file but no content is placed there. Please suggest what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You never open the file for WriteAccess. I have included code from my working app. First do this command

```
 StorageFile ageFile = await local.CreateFileAsync("Age.txt", CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
```

then do this:

```
// Get the file. 
var ageFile = await local.OpenStreamForWriteAsync("Age.txt",CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists); 
// Read the data. 
using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(ageFile)) 
{ 
  streamWriter.WriteLine(cmbAgeGroup.SelectedIndex + ";" + DateTime.Now); 
  streamWriter.Flush(); 
} 
ageFile.Dispose();
```